# Razor dynamic table creation c#

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have nested lists of objects passed through to the razor view from the controller.

If the nested list count is greater than 10, I need the first 10 objects to render in the first column and then the remaining to render in a second column.

I have tried everything within my power to make this happen! Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I have had most success with .Skip() and .Take() methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aha so what you want is

item01 item11 item21

item02 item12 item22

...

You need to loop thru for rows 0-9 and decide which item appears in which column. If this is correct, then make Items an array... hope this helps...

```
@for(row=0; row<10; ++row){
    <tr>
    @for(col=0; col<5;++col){
        var idx = col * 10 + row;
        if(idx>=Model.items.length){
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        }else{
            var itm = Model.items[col * 10 + row];
            <td>itm</td>
        }
    }
    </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ajd. I have taken the above approach. However, the issue I have is that I am creating a td element for each itm. I need to create a 2 td elements in the same tr element (1 for the first group of 10 and one for the second group of 10).

Comment: This is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

Comment: <table>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<tr>
<td>Item1</td>
<td>item2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>item3</td>
<td>item4</td>
</tr>
</table>